# WordPress Synology File Permissions

Tags: wordpress, security, file-permissions, synology

I'm running a number of WordPress instancies on my Synology server (custom setup not the Synology package). That are accessible to the www. I need WordPress to be able to edit files on my server (ie edit theme from the theme editor, cache plugin update cache etc). For this to work I have to allow the HTML synology user write permissions to the folders on my server. Am I creating a security issue? Ie does this mean anyone can use HTTP to edit those files on my server?

Synology DS215J running 6.0.2 DSM
WordPress 4.61

Answer (score 0):

In regular Wordpress (installed on a 'conventional' server) you also should make certain files (e.g. style.css from your child theme) public writable in order to edit this within the WP environment.
In your case, you only grant access to a user on your own NAS system. Sounds very non-risky to me.